# Eslint can't resolve paths for Solid.js tsx extensions

Tags: typescript, eslint, solid-js

When I try importing TSX components (without the extension), Eslint says that it cannot resolve the path:

[image: no extension]

However, when I include the TSX extension, it says that I should remove it:

[image: with extension]

This is my .eslintrc.yaml config:

```yaml
env:
  browser: true
  es2021: true
extends:
  - airbnb-base
  - eslint:recommended
  - plugin:solid/typescript
  - prettier
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
parserOptions:
  ecmaVersion: latest
  sourceType: module
plugins:
  - prettier
  - simple-import-sort
  - solid
  - "@typescript-eslint"
rules:
  import/extensions:
    - error
    - always
    - pattern:
        tsx: never
  prettier/prettier:
    - error
  simple-import-sort/imports: error
  simple-import-sort/exports: error
```

I'm using Solid.js, so I didn't select the `React` option when initializing my eslintrc. Is there a way I can tell Eslint to ignore the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Adding these options to my eslintrc fixed the problem

```
extends:
  - airbnb-typescript/base

parserOptions:
  project: tsconfig.json

settings:
  import/resolver:
    node:
      extensions:
        - .tsx
```